# Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra and let $B \in \mathcal{F}$. Show that $\mathcal{G} = \{A \cap B: A \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra and let $B \in \mathcal{F}$. Show that $\mathcal{G} = \{A \cap B: A \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra of subsets of $B$.

To show that $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we need to show that:

(a) $\emptyset \in \mathcal{G}$. This is clear, because $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$ and that $\emptyset = B \cap \emptyset$. Therefore $ \emptyset \in \mathcal{G}$.

(b) If $A_1, A_2, \ldots \in\mathcal{F}$, then
$$\bigcup_i (A_i \cap B) = (\bigcup_i A_i)\cap B \in \mathcal{G}.$$

(c)If $A \in \mathcal{F}$, then $A^c \in \mathcal{F}$, then I need to show that
$$A^c \cap B \in \mathcal{G}.$$

First, since $A ,B  \in \mathcal{F}$, then $A \cap B \in \mathcal{F}$ and that $B -(A\cap B) \in \mathcal{F}$. Also,
$$B - (A \cap B) = A^c\cap B,$$
so that $A^c \cap B \in \mathcal{G}$ as required.

Is this reasoning correct? or im missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost correct, but (c) isn't quite stated right.  What you want to show is that if $C\in\mathcal{G}$, then $C^c\in\mathcal{G}$ as well.  Note here that $C^c$ means the complement of $C$ *as a subset of $B$*, i.e. $B-C$.  Since $C\in\mathcal{G}$, you can write $C=A\cap B$ for some $A\in\mathcal{F}$.  So what you need to prove is that if $A\in\mathcal{F}$, then $B-(A\cap B)$ can be written in the form $A'\cap B$ for some $A'\in\mathcal{F}$.  From what you've written, you should be able to see how to choose $A'$.

(Similarly, in part (b), you should really start by supposing $C_1,C_2,\ldots\in\mathcal{G}$, and then choose $A_1,A_2,\ldots\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $C_i=A_i\cap B$.  What you've written then proves that $\bigcup C_i\in \mathcal{G}$.)

Comment: thank you very much. This helps a lot.

Comment: The collection $\mathcal G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $B$, whether or not $B$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Relative to B, $(A \cap B)^c=B-(A \cup B)=B \cap(A \cup B)^c=B\cap A^c \cup \emptyset=B\cap A^c$, so since A is in F, $A^c$ is also in F, QED.